# Flipping and maintaining aspect ratio of a chart in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to create a horizontal histogram, and adjust the chart aspect ratio using `ggplot2` .

For example let's say my chart is `dia <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=color)) + geom_bar()`.

I can flip this to be horizontal using `dia + coord_flip()`.

I can also adjust the aspect ratio e.g. `dia + coord_fixed(ratio=.001)`.

But when I combine them `dia  + coord_flip()+ coord_fixed(ratio=.001)`, the chart is no longer horizontal.

Is there any way to achieve what I want using `ggplot2`?

Comment: do you need the aspect ratio set with respect to the data (axes), or would adjusting the panel's aspect ratio be good enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[See this answer on the ggplot2 mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/AEnqaD7UGBA) :

> You can only use one coord_*() function on a given ggplot since it
>   changes the coordinate system after everything else has been done. To
>   change the aspect ratio, you can use the corresponding argument in the
>   theming system:

```
 + coord_flip() + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
```

Comment: Is this answer correct? As far as I can tell the theme aspect ratio refers to the shape of the panel, while coord_fixed refers to that of the data.