# ggplot2: Flip axes and maintain aspect ratio of data

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

In ggplot2, the `coord_fixed()` coordinate system ensures that the aspect ratio of the data is maintained at a given value. So, the shape of the panel changes to maintain the shape of the data. Meanwhile `coord_flip()` swaps the axes of the plot. However, a plot in ggplot2 must have exactly one coordinate system, so these functions cannot be combined.

My question is:

> Does there exist a way to combine the behaviours of `coord_fixed()` and `coord_flip()`, resulting in a coordinate system with the x and y axes exchanged and a fixed aspect ratio of the data?

This is a popular question, however the common answer is incorrect:

- [How do I to fix aspect ratio and apply coord_flip in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35799426/how-do-i-to-fix-aspect-ratio-and-apply-coord-flip-in-ggplot2)
- [Flipping and maintaining aspect ratio of a chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011410/flipping-and-maintaining-aspect-ratio-of-a-chart-in-ggplot2)

The commonly suggested answer is to use `coord_flip()` together with `theme(aspect.ratio = 1)` instead of `coord_fixed()`. However, as per the ggplot2 documentation, this setting refers to the "aspect ratio of the panel." Thus, the data will change shape to maintain the shape of the panel.

I suspect that this is a feature that does not currently exist in ggplot2. But more importantly I think that a correct solution or at least response to this question should be documented.

Quick minimal example of the issue:

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- 1:100; data <- data.frame(x = x, y = x * 2)
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()

p # by default panel and data both fit to device window
p + coord_fixed() # panel changes shape to maintain shape of data
p + theme(aspect.ratio = 1) # data changes shape to maintain shape of panel
p + coord_fixed() + coord_flip() # coord_flip() overwrites coord_fixed()

# popular suggested answer does not maintain aspect ratio of data:
p + coord_flip() + theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree that the `theme` solution isn't *really* a proper one. Here is a solution that does work programatically by calculating the aspect from the actual axes ranges stored in the plot object, but it takes a few lines of code:

```
ranges <- ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_ranges[[1]][c('x.range', 'y.range')]
sizes <- sapply(ranges, diff)
aspect <- sizes[1] / sizes[2]

p + coord_flip() + theme(aspect.ratio = aspect)
```

[image]

The solution I would probably use in practice, is to use the horizontal geoms in the `ggstance` package (although this may not always be feasible).

*Note:* This will only give the exact correct answer for two continuous scales with an equal multiplicative `extend` argument (i.e. the default).

*edit:* In many cases I would recommend using `coord_equal` combined with the `ggstance` package instead of this solution.

Comment: Cheers, I think that solution is the best that currently exists. (But regarding your first sentence -- the `theme` solution is just wrong, no qualification necessary. I am looking at spatial data and it is critical to know whether the data is being shown in its true shape. The `theme` solution can have the opposite effect and distort data further.)

Comment: @mb7744 I was merely referring to the fact that for _many_ people (but certainly not all) the original solution is fine. I'm not disagreeing with you (which is why I answered the question).

Comment: Sure---but what I'm getting is that that it may only be fine for people that don't notice the difference, and misinterpret their plot. I think this is why the last two questions about this on SO have incorrect accepted answers. But this is just me nitpicking. I appreciate your solution!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just flipping the `x` and `y` arguments in the `aes` specification. So for example instead of:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=wt,y=drat))+geom_point()+coord_fixed()
```

I did:

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=drat,y=wt))+geom_point()+coord_fixed()
```