# how to fit multiple ggplot charts on a a4 pdf?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot, patchwork

Consider this simple example

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)
library(patchwork)

mytib <- tibble(group = as.factor(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)),
       y = c(1,2,3,42,50,400,3,3,2,3,3,4),
       x = c('a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d'))


p1 <- mytib %>% ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = group)) +
  geom_col() + ggtitle('this is a messy chart')+
  coord_flip()+
  xlab('Hello') +
  ylab('This is a nice comment')
```

Now I use `patchwork` to combine the charts so that I obtain 3 rows of 3 charts each on a regular `a4` pdf page

```
(p1 + p1 + p1)/
(p1 + p1 + p1)/
(p1 + p1 + p1)

ggsave(file="a4_output.pdf", width = 210, height = 297, units = "mm")
```

[image]

The output is a nice a4 `pdf` but the problem is that the charts on the `pdf` are very stretched. Is there a way to preserve their original ratio (on the pdf) so that they look less stretched, even three on a single row? I dont mind if they look smaller.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there something keeping you from using `ggplot2::facet_*`? It would save space used on redundant legends, redundant axes, multiple titles (which can be accomplished via facet labels, though different look).

Comment: thanks for your help. The issue is that the charts come from different datasets, so I cannot easily use facet_grid. There has to be another way (I hope :) )

Comment: Add an empty row at the bottom. Do e.g. 5 rows with the last ones being just `ggplot()`.

Comment: Is it just "different datasets", or are the completely different looking data? If the structure is similiar-enough, you can `bind_rows` the columns you need, adding a column to indicate the origin dataset, which can be used as the facet label.

Comment: completely different charts. @Axeman that looks like a crazy trick :)

Comment: If you shift the legends to the bottom `theme(legend.position="bottom")`, it'll have a strong effect on the aspect ratio.

Comment: I know but assume you have to keep the charts as is. I guess the only way to achieve the expected result is to make the charts smaller...

Comment: Rotate to landscape?

Comment: I have to keep it a4 portrait. that is the constraint. I mean this must be pretty common. You write a report and you want to show 6 cute little charts on a single page...

Comment: As Axeman suggested, add one or more empty rows. Or just constrain the figure height so that it is not as tall as an a4 page. Sorry, I don't have much more to add.

Comment: I guess the empty plot solution is the easiest. Have a look also at https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html  You can pretty exactly control the layout specifying it with something like `layout = '#ABCD' etc` it must be a rectangle but it sets the relative dimensions of each plot, and the hash key is an empty space

Comment: but the empty plot does not work for me. can you make it work with the layout in patchwork then?

Comment: @Axeman your previous answer helped find one solution :) Thanks

Comment: Hey I have added another solution, hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the changing plot ratio. Now, `coord_flip` doesn't work with fixed ratio - but [user Axeman explained how to deal with this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42116523/7941188) - use `ggstance`!! I changed the plot mildly, using `geom_colh`, switched your x and y, and added a fixed ratio. Now we can use your plot layout, or simply pack the plots in a list and use `wrap_plots`. I did not use the `reprex` output because I am sharing the screenshot from the pdf output.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
library(ggstance)

mytib <- tibble(group = as.factor(c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)),
                y = c(1,2,3,42,50,400,3,3,2,3,3,4),
                x = c('a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d'))

p1 <- 
  mytib %>% ggplot(aes(x = y, y = x, fill = group)) +
  geom_colh() + ggtitle('this is a messy chart')+
  coord_fixed(100)+
  xlab('Hello') +
  ylab('This is a nice comment')

plotlist <- list()
for(i in 1:9) { plotlist[[i]] <- p1 }

ggsave(plot = wrap_plots(plotlist), file="a4_output.pdf", width = 210, height = 297, units = "mm")
```

[image]

**Another solution** is to add another row - not with an empty plot, but using `plot_layout`

```
(p1 + p1 + p1)/
  (p1 + p1 + p1)/
  (p1 + p1 + p1) +
  plot_layout(nrow = 4)
```