# eqscplot equivalent in ggplot2 for maps (geom_sf & coord_sf)

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, scale, aspect-ratio

I'm looking for a `ggplot2` equivalent for `eqscplot` (package `MASS`) that can fill the entire plot window while maintaining the scale within a map in a `ggplot`.

There is `coord_fixed` [where cartesian coordinates can be set with fixed ratios](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/coord_fixed.html) (argument `aspect =`), but it doesn't work if I'm using `geom_sf()`; `geom_sf()` requires `coord_sf` for a plot to be drawn and can't be a `ggplot` layer if `coord_sf` is a layer.

There is this answer ([ggplot2: Flip axes and maintain aspect ratio of data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42116523/5491790)) but it's not automatic, which is a problem when there are a lot of maps to be made and where automated map making is the ideal workflow. It also doesn't zoom into the points like `eqscplot` does.

`eqscplot` is able to maintain an aspect ratio when the `range` of `x` and `y` values are widely different, which is helpful for plotting maps.

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)

world <- ne_countries(scale = 'medium', returnclass = 'sf',
                      country = c('India', 'Sri Lanka', 'Pakistan', 'Myanmar', 
                                  'Malaysia', 'Indonesia', 'Thailand', 
                                  'Nepal', 'Bhutan', 'Laos', 'China', 'Iran',
                                  'Maldives'))

RNGkind('Mers')
set.seed(42)

lonlat <- data.frame(lon = rnorm(10, 80, 5),
                     lat = rnorm(10, 12, 5))
apply(lonlat, 2, range)
          lon       lat
[1,] 77.17651  9.343545
[2,] 90.09212 14.286645

eqscplot(lonlat$lon, lonlat$lat, type = 'n')
plot(world, add = T, col = NA)
points(lonlat$lon, lonlat$lat, col = 'red', pch = 16)
#Compare the lon/lat ranges on the map with the ranges of the data's longitude and latitude
```

[image]

I was was looking to see if there was a way to do it `ggplot2`, but if I don't specify the limits of the longitude and latitude, it takes the extent of the countries I specified in the `world` object.

```
ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_point(data = lonlat, aes(x = lon, y = lat))
```

[image]

I've got a few hundred maps to make so automating the process with `apply` family of functions or `for` loops is preferred. But I need something that can automatically zoom into the points that I'm plotting while maintaining the the aspect ratio. I'm looking to do it in `ggplot2` because my collaborators aren't as experienced with `R` and were taught how to use the `tidyverse`, so anything I can do to make the code easier for them to understand can go a long way.

**My question is:** Is there an `eqscplot` equivalent in `ggplot2`? Something where the aspect ratio can be set automatically, zooms into where the points are instead of the extent of the `world` polygon, and fills the entire plot window while maintaining the scales?

Answer (score 0):

Using `geom_sf` it looks like the plots will adjust to show the extent of the largest object.  You can use `st_crop` to adjust the data that is too large.  It might help to make all of your objects sf collections, rather than using both geom_sf and geom_point.

Below is a quick example that you can adjust to change the bounding box of the maps.  A good post by @Jindra-Lacko on adjusting bounding boxes can be found here: https://www.jla-data.net/eng/adjusting-bounding-box-of-a-tmap-map/

Though most of it is using tmap, it should apply to ggplot2 as well.

```r
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.2, GDAL 2.2.3, PROJ 4.9.3

world <- ne_countries(scale = 'medium', returnclass = 'sf',
                      country = c('India', 'Sri Lanka', 'Pakistan', 'Myanmar', 
                                  'Malaysia', 'Indonesia', 'Thailand', 
                                  'Nepal', 'Bhutan', 'Laos', 'China', 'Iran',
                                  'Maldives'))

RNGkind('Mers')
set.seed(42)

lonlat <- data.frame(lon = rnorm(10, 80, 5),
                     lat = rnorm(10, 12, 5))
#apply(lonlat, 2, range)
# lon       lat
# [1,] 77.17651  9.343545
# [2,] 90.09212 14.286645

# eqscplot(lonlat$lon, lonlat$lat, type = 'n')
# plot(world, add = T, col = NA)
#points(lonlat$lon, lonlat$lat, col = 'red', pch = 16)
#Compare the lon/lat ranges on the map with the ranges of the data's longitude and latitude

#make lonlat an sf object
lonlat_sf <- st_as_sf(lonlat, 
                      coords = c('lon', 'lat')) %>%
  st_set_crs(st_crs(world))

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = lonlat_sf, color = 'red') +
  geom_sf(data = world %>% st_crop(lonlat_sf, world ), fill = NA) +
  coord_sf()
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_intersection assumes that they are planar
#> Warning: attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all
#> geometries
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

When I have this issue with different aspect ratios. I create a buffer for the output dimension i want and save using the same scales similar to below..

```
library(buffers)

#Find bbox and bbox_centroid
bbox <- st_as_sfc(st_bbox(df))
bbox_centroid<-st_centroid(bbox)

#Calculate Max distance from centroid
max_dist=as.numeric(max(st_distance(bbox_centroid,bbox)))

#Create buffer (In this case I wanted a rectangular image output)
#Notice I'm using a 1.5 ratio for x_length to y_length, 3/2=1.5)
rectangle_buf=buffer_rectangle(bbox_centroid,x_length=max_dist*2,y_length=max_dist*3)

#Find bbox minumum and maximum X and Y values
bbox_rect<-st_as_sf(rectangle_buf)
bbox<-st_bbox(bbox_rect)

#Create ggplot2 image and save with correct dimensions
ggplot(df)+geom_sf()+
#Important part of code
coord_sf(xlim = c(bbox[1], bbox[3]), ylim = c(bbox[2], bbox[4]), expand = T)

##Save ggplot with correct dimensions (In my case this is would be a 1 to 1.5 ratio)
ggsave(plot=last_plot(),width=3,height= 3* 1.5)
```